# SQL Error When Using ibm_db to Connect To Database

Tags: python, db2

**My Problem:** When I attempt to connect to DB2 using the python package ibm_db, I receive the following error:

SQLCODE=-30073][CLI Driver] SQL30073N  "0x0000" Parameter value "0x0000" is not supported.  SQLSTATE=58017

The code is as follows.

```
import ibm_db
conn_str = "DRIVER=IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER;DATABASE=XXXXXX_XX_X;HOSTNAME=XXXXXXX.XX.XXX.XXX;PORT=XXXX;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=XXXX;PWD=XXXX;"
connection = ibm_db.connect(conn_str, "", "")
```

The Xs above represent an alphanumeric character. Is there a particular reason why I am receiving this error?

Here are locations I have searched but was unable to find anything:

https://github.com/ibmdb/node-ibm_db/issues/450
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/codes/src/tpc/n30073.html
https://www.sqlerror.de/db2_sql_error_-30073_sqlstate_58017.html

Thanks for any help!

Edit 7/30/2020: @mao, thanks for the feedback. Here are additional facts:

**Question 1:** What is your operating-system that runs Python? Your python version?

**Answer 1:** 64-bit 2016 Windows Server 2016 Standard. (With Python 3.7.4)

**Question 2:** The version of ibm_db module?

**Answer 2:** ibm_db-3.0.2-py3.7

**Question 3:** What is the text output of the clidriver db2level command?

**Answer 3:** Looked at logs in here: C:\ProgramData\IBM\DB2\C_PROGRA~1_IBM_NTX64_~1_CLIDRI~1\db2diag.log

2020-07-29-15.19.38.831000-240 I26899F365           LEVEL: Warning
PID     : 5276                 TID : 7616           PROC : python.exe
INSTANCE:                      NODE : 000
HOSTNAME: XXX
EDUID   : 7616
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, bsu security, sqlexLogPluginMessage, probe:20
DATA #1 : String with size, 43 bytes
loadAuthidMapper: GetModuleHandle rc = 126

2020-07-29-15.19.38.965000-240 I27266F371           LEVEL: Warning
PID     : 5276                 TID : 7616           PROC : python.exe
INSTANCE:                      NODE : 000
HOSTNAME: XXX
EDUID   : 7616
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, common communication, sqlcctcplogIPAddress, probe:50
MESSAGE : SQL10007N  Message "3220" could not be retrieved.  Reason code: "3".

**Question 4:** What is the target Db2-server platform and version?

**Answer 4:**

**Question 5:** Is it Db2-for-Z/OS?

**Answer 5:** Yes.

**Question 6:**  Are you able to create a DSN and test connectivity with the db2cli tool via db2cli validate -dsn XXX -connect -user xxx - passwd zzzzzz method ?

**Answer 6:** When attempting to do so, I receive the following error:

## Connection attempt for data source name "XXXXX":

[FAILED]: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1531N  The connection failed because the name specified with the DSN connection string keyword could not be found in either the db2dsdriver.cfg configuration file or the db2cli.ini configuration file.  Data source name specified in the connection string: "XXXXX".

[IBM][CLI Driver] CLI0124E  Invalid argument value. SQLSTATE=HY009

Comment: Please EDIT your question to add facts. What is your operating-system that runs Python? Your python version? The version of `ibm_db` module? What is the text output of the clidriver `db2level` command?  What is the target Db2-server platform and version? Is it Db2-for-Z/OS?  Are you able to create a DSN and test connectivity with the `db2cli` tool via `db2cli validate -dsn XXX -connect -user xxx - passwd zzzzzz` method ?

Comment: the `db2level.exe` is in the clidriver subdirectory named 'bin'. .  Please also add the version of the Db2-for-Z/os and which mode the Db2-subsystem is in.  Double check the connection details, host, port, userid, password.

Comment: To make the DSN, learn how to edit the `db2dsdriver.cfg` file (default location in the CFG subdirectory of the clidriver). You can edit it either with an XML editor, or via using special command lines of the `db2cli.exe` tool per the IBM documentation online in the Db2 Knowledge Center. Also, if the clidriver is properly registered with MS-Windows you can use odbcad32 (with matching bitness to python+ibm_db) to make the DSN and it will populate the `db2dsdriver.cfg` for you.

Comment: Im getting this error when I try to connect: [FAILED]: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30082N  Security processing failed with reason "17" ("UNSUPPORTED FUNCTION").  SQLSTATE=08001

Comment: Please show (in your question) the command-line that gave the above SQL30082N message.

Comment: Command -> db2cli validate -dsn XXX -connect

Comment: Does the basic validation of the XML file complete successfully (before you try the connection) ?  `db2cli  validate `

Comment: Apart from the need to get a successful `db2cli validate` (no other options) before you try to validate the connection, when you then do try to connect, you need to give additional parameters `-user xxxx -password xxxx` to the `-connect $DSN ` validation.

Comment: Hi Mao, thanks so much for your patience and assistance. Yes, when I validate via ```db2cli validate``` , I get:    ===============================================================================
db2dsdriver.cfg schema validation for the entire file:
===============================================================================

Success: The schema validation completed successfully without any errors.

===============================================================================
The validation is completed.

Comment: When I do the command: ```db2cli validate -connect -dsn "IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER" -user XXXX -password XXXX```, I get an error saying: Error: db2cli sees an invalid option.

Comment: the DSN is the data source name (what you called the database in the DSN clause in your `db2dsriver.cfg` ). So repeat the command with the correct value in the `-dsn xxx` clause xxx=your database name

Comment: <database host="XXXX" name="XXXX" port="XXX">                                                    Are you referring to the name attribute in the XML?

Comment: Either the `alias=XXX` (if you defined an alias, it is optional) or the `name=XXX` value from the XML in the db2dsdriver.cfg.

Answer (score 0):

For others who might see the specific symptom **"GetModuleHandle rc = 126"** in the **clidriver** `db2diag.log` in specific situations on Microsoft-Windows, one possibile explanation is that two required DLL files are not on the PATH at run time, which are needed by clidriver in some configurations.

*Note that there can be other explanations for the symptom.*

You also must ensure that the GSK files as supplied by default with clidriver are in a directory that is on the PATH (typically this is the **icc64** or icc86 subdirectories of clidriver\bin).

The workaround is to arrange that the two files "**msvcp120.dll**" and "**msvcr120.dll**" are both on the PATH.  clidriver delivers both of these files, but stores them in a directory that is not on the PATH by default.

For the 64-bit clidriver they are in the directory `...\clidriver\bin\amd64.vc12.crt` (relative to wherever the clidriver got unpacked).

For the 32-bit clidriver they are in the directory `...\clidriver\bin\x86.vc12.crt` (relative to the directory where clidriver got unpacked).

For python ibm_db (and it related ibm_db_sa and ibm_db_django) , the clidriver location by default will be under the site-packages directory, whose absolute path is visible in the output of the command `pip show ibm_db`.

You can either copy these two files into a directory that is already on the PATH (for example the `clidriver\bin` directory), **or** you can extend the PATH environment variable for that session to include the relevant directory that contains these files.